# gconf-editor not showing apps

Tags: wingpanel

Have installed gconf-editor in loki but the only app showing is gconf-editor. How can I access the other folders? (I would like to hide the clock from the wingpanel)

[image]

Comment: Do you want to hide the clock only or together with the date?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing dconf-editor instead, I get plenty more folders in there.

Also, if you want to hide the indicator totally (date AND time), open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt remove wingpanel-indicator-datetime
```

(If you want to get it back, do:

```
sudo apt install wingpanel-indicator-datetime
```